# BERT GENERATIVE MODEL

Tags: natural-language

I am asking if bert can be used as a generative model.In fact I read the paper  BERT has a Mouth, and It Must Speak: BERT as a Markov Random Field Language Model using MCMC sampling. However, I am asking if there is other techniques or ideas to sample from bert. In fact, I will explain the problem that I want to solve: I want to mask a span of tokens ( Contiguous tokens from a sentence) and generate a new span using the rest of the sentence, this span can be of any length. For example : I eat delicious pizza with friends, I am going to mask delicious pizza so the sentence will be I eat [MASK][MASK] with friends and generate suggestions instead of the MASK.

Someone can help me with ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This can, of course, work fine. People tried this approach e.g., for [extending knowledge bases](https://arxiv.org/abs/1909.01066) or [cloze-style question answering](https://arxiv.org/abs/1911.03343). The tricky issue you need to deal with is the subword segmentation. The proper way would be trying different numbers of `[MASK]` tokens to cover multiple possible subword segmentations. The problem here is that you need to somehow compare the score of sequences of different lengths.

Pre-trained sequence-to-sequence models like [BART](https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.13461) or [MASS](https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.02450) might be a better fit for your task. They mask-out a part of a source sentence and train a sequence-to-sequence model to generate the missing part.

Comment: I read MASS paper, I think it is based on transformers, can we change the architecture to BERT ? Adding to that, can we deal with the masking length, for example generating any span of words with different lengths keeping the right part and the left part of the mask unchanged? Is it possbile to have different suggestions as the example mentionned (pizza becomes delicious food?)

Comment: The idea in fact is filling multiple contiguous gaps in a sentence